# Algorithm for putting double border around isosceles triangle

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I've been trying to figure out the best way to draw double border around an isosceles triangle in source code. I would like to draw something like the following:

[image]

I've tried two approaches neither of which work.

1. First the naive approach. Enlarge the bounding box and redraw the triangle inside the larger box. Problem is that the space between the two triangles is uneven. A bit of algebra shows why this is the case.  See next image:

[image]

2. Scale the triangle relative to the center point. I do this by translating the 'center' of the triangle to the origin, scale and translate back. I compute the center using cx = (x1+x2+x3)/3, and cy = (y1+y2+y3)/3 (centroid center), and x and y are the coordinatess of the vertices. If I do this I get the following image which is obviously not right either.

[image]

Question. I think approach number two should work but I am using the right center when scaling?

Comment: is the triangle always vertically aligned? you can only scale if the triangle is equilateral btw

Comment: Yes its always vertically aligned but not necessarily equilateral.

Comment: yeh so you cant scale it

Comment: Surely he can always scale it, just not around a naive centre point? Per an answer I'm halfway through but would prefer not to post if my logic is flawed: the outer has parallel sides to the inner. Therefore it has the same angles at each corner. Therefore it is similar. Therefore it is a scaled version of the original.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but it boiled down to : use vectors! It's the easiest way.

Comment: @Tommy if he scales it, then each new vertex, its old counterpart, and the centeroid, would be colinear. this does _not_ give equally spaced borders (think of a really narrow triangle - the longer borders will be narrower)

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah that's only if you make a huge assumption about the centre of scaling. The outer triangle will be a scaled copy of the inner, or else explain the flaw in the logic presented above.

Comment: @Tommy true yeh, svs cleared that up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scaling center you should use is the [Incenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter) and not the [Centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid). You could find the incenter using the formula:

```
((a*x1+b*x2+c*x3)/(a+b+c), (a*y1+b*y2+c*y3)/(a+b+c))
```

where `a` is the length of the side opposite to the point `(x1, y1)`, `b` - the opposite to `(x2, y2)` and `c` - `(x3, y3)`.

Visual proof:
[image]

Notice that it is irrelevant whether the triangle is isosceles.

Comment: if you are interested I can add a proof too but it's not very exciting and I don't think this is the right site for this.

Comment: A proof would be very interesting to look at. I'm going to try this now.

Comment: @rhody I added visual proof. I hope this helps :)

Comment: That is amazing, it worked! I struggled with this last night and this morning.